# If else statements in web forms to calculate score in javascript or HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, calculator

Im trying to create a simple web form to calculate a score from raw data.

For example field A (numeric) : if number less than 100 return number 1, if 100-150 return number 2 and if more than 100 return number 3.

Same idea for fields B and C

Then on submit the form adds up all the returned numbers, and directs the user to a different page depending on the result.

For example: 
Field A user enters 100 (so scores 1)
Field B user enters 140 (so scores 2)
Field C user enters 200 (so scores 3)

total score is therefore 6 and so user would be directed to webpage for score 6.

I hope this makes sense? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: show some html and js and tell us where exactly you're facing problems

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Jquery maybe something like this ( not test )

```
$("#BT").click(function(){

test();
})
function test(){
var score1 =0;
var score2 =0;
var score3 =0;
var finalscore =0;

if($("#yourfildA").val()!=""){
   score1 = parseInt($("#yourfildA").val());
}

if($("#yourfildB").val()!=""){
   score2 = parseInt($("#yourfildB").val());
}

if($("#yourfildC").val()!=""){
   score3 = parseInt($("#yourfildC").val());
}



if(score1==100){
finalscore +=1
}

if(score2==140){
finalscore += 2;
}

if(score3==200){
finalscore += 3;
}
    alert(finalscore);
if(finalscore ==6){
   // refirect
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jcB4/10/

Comment: LOL Muhammad , now I think is ok :)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help. Im a total JS nube so i've tried to get it working from a mixture of your suggestions but no joy. Here is what I have:

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(){
var A= document.getElementByID('field A ID').value;
var B= document.getElementByID('field B ID').value;
var C= document.getElementByID('field C ID').value;
var sum=calc(A)+calc(B)+calc(C);
switch (sum){
                    case 3:
                        //get option and change it's attr
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        //get option and change it's attr
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        //get option and change it's attr
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        //get option and change it's attr

                        break;
                    case 7:
                        //get option and change it's attr
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        //get option and change it's attr
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        //get option and change it's attr
                        break;
}
}

function calc(value){
if(value<100){
return 1;
}else if(value>100 &&value<150){
return 2;
}else{
return 3;
}
}
```

is that so?